# Delete Mail with Python Outlook IMAP

Tags: python, imap

I´m trying to delete my mails in my outlook mail account.

This code :

```
 for message_to_delete in messages:
            print(message_to_delete)
            server.store(message_to_delete, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
        print(server.expunge())
```

wont work. the last print returns:

```
b'584'
('OK', [None])
```

Is there a different flag in outlook? Or what could be the problem?

Greetings